# android 2.2 minimum hardware requirement

Tags: android, embedded

May anyone tell me the minimum hardware requirement for an embedded board to run Android 2.2. I have s3c2440 FriendlyARM board, I searched and found that it even cannot run Android 1.5 smoothly. Any suggestions are appreciated, Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no official minimum processor requirements for an Android 2.2 device. (Different story for 3.0 most likely.)

If the board can run 1.5 to some degree, it may also be able to run 2.2. I don't think Android has gotten slower from 1.5 to 2.2. My phone was originally a 1.5 device and now runs 2.2. If anything it has gotten faster, thanks to numerous improvements that have been made.

Google does publish a "Compatibility Definition Document" that lays out the hardware and software requirements to make an Android device with the Market and other Google apps. That may or may not apply depending on what kind of project you are working on.

http://source.android.com/compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf

Answer (score 1):

QVGA (240 x 320 pixels) touchscreen
Virtual keyboard support;
Must have a USB connection that connects to a standard USB-A port
92MB RAM; 150MB user storage
2-megapixel camera
Home, Menu, and Back functions available at all times
Wireless high-speed data standard capable of supporting 200Kbps; like EDGE, EV-DO, HSPA, 802.11g (Android 1.6 requires Wi-Fi)
Accelerometer
Compass
GPS receiver
Bluetooth transceiver